# JSON Parsing in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I've done the Raywenderlich tutorial about JSON in iOS but I got difficulties to adapt it to my own JSON file. Here is **my JSON**:

```
{
    "Albumvideo":[
    {
        "titre": "PublicitÃ©",
        "photo":"blabla.jpg"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Events",
        "photo":"blabla.jpg"
    }
    ]
}
```

Here is **my Code**:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async (kBgQueue, ^{
         NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:lienAlbumsVideo];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
     NSError* error;
     NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
     NSArray* albumsvideo = [json objectForKey:@"titre"];
     NSLog(@"Album: %@", albumsvideo);
}
```

Log returns `null`.

Comment: try logging the error: NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription])

Comment: @nic Please include your JSON in the question itself. Questions are supposed to be self-contained and links tend to stop working after a while.

Comment: The json is in in the question!

Comment: Did you make sure `responseData` is not `nil` or at least what you expect to get back from the server?

Comment: @bl it wasn't at the time.

Comment: Sure I made a copy and paste.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You have filled your JSON Data in your Dictionary (named `json`) correctly. But then you have an `Array of Dictionaries` (called `Albumvideo`) inside your Main `Dictionary` and value of `titre` is inside `Albumvideo` Array.

**The Correct Code is :**

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray* albumsvideo = [json objectForKey:@"Albumvideo"];
NSString *titre1 = [[albumsvideo objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"titre"];
NSString *titre2 = [[albumsvideo objectAtIndex:1]valueForKey:@"titre"];
```

Understand the Concept. It depends on what you have inside your `JSON`. If it's an Array ( Values inside `[ ]`) then you have to save in `NSArray`, if it's a Dictionary ( Values inside `{ }`) then save as `NSDictionary` and if you have single values like string , integer, double then you have to save them using appropriate Objective-C Data types.

Hope, you got some proper idea about **JSON Parsing**.

Comment: +1.  Excellent explanation, and it's entirely correct (unlike the others)

Comment: Sound's great :-) Is it the same process if I have array inside other array (in my JSON)? I've made this for my "titre" : NSArray *titre = [albumsvideo valueForKey:@"titre"];

Comment: @NicolasWilhem : Understand the Concept. It depends on what you have inside your JSON. If it's an Array then you have to save in NSArray, if it's a Dictionary then save as NSDictionary and if you have single values like string , integer, double then you have to save them using appropriate Objective-C Data types.

Comment: Thank you guys, with you I learned faster and better than reading tons of incomplete tutorial. I now have a good starting point.

Comment: @NicolasWilhem: Don't Edit the Question. You should ask a new One.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Vin is right. Basically, to parse json response look at the kind of bracket used. 
 Start parsing with the outer symbol and check for the symbol. If it is,
1) `{` then it is NSDictionary.
2) `[` then it is NSArray. 
These simple rules will make your life easy. :)

Answer (score -2):

For all the bigginers out there. this will help you

```
     synch.m
    ========

    #import "thenewapi.h"



    @interface thenewapi ()

    {

    NSData *data;

    NSMutableArray*mutarray;

    int index;

    NSString *s;

    NSMutableArray *arr;

    NSMutableArray *imgarr;



}



@end



@implementation thenewapi



- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    index=0;

    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ir.com/wecare/api/partnership/partnership_heading?format=json"]];

    NSURLResponse *response=nil;

    NSError *error=nil;

    data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    mutarray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];



    arr=[mutarray valueForKey:@"0"];

       _idlbl.text=[arr valueForKey:@"id"];

    _titlelbl.text=[arr valueForKey:@"title"];

   _destxtvw.text=[arr valueForKey:@"description"];



    imgarr=[mutarray valueForKey:@"images"];



  s=[[imgarr objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"image"];



    NSString *f=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://irtech.com/wecare/uploads/partnership/%@",s];



    NSURL *g=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:f];



    data=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:g];

    self.imgvw.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];









    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}



- (IBAction)clickbtn:(id)sender

{

    ++index;

        s=[[imgarr objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"image"];



        NSString *f=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://irdtech.com/wecare/uploads/partnership/%@",s];



        NSURL *g=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:f];

        data=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:g];

        self.imgvw.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];



}

========================================================================================================




Asynch.h
========

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface thenewAsynch : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgvw;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tbl;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *click;







@end



Asynch.m
========


#import "thenewAsynch.h"



@interface thenewAsynch ()

{

    NSDictionary *dic;

    NSMutableArray *mutarray;

    NSMutableData *mutdata;

    NSString *s;

    NSArray *arr;

    NSArray *imgarr;

    NSData *data;

    int index;

}



@end



@implementation thenewAsynch



- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];



    mutarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    mutdata=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];

    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://irtech.com/wecare/api/partnership/partnership_heading?format=json"]];

    NSURLConnection *connect=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"Connection String=%@",connect);

    [self.view addSubview:_tbl];



    arr=[mutarray valueForKey:@"0"];



    imgarr=[mutarray valueForKey:@"images"];













    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

{

    return arr.count;



}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{

    static NSString *cellid=@"Cell Identifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];

    if(cell==nil)

    {

        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];

    }

    if(indexPath.row==0)

    {

        cell.textLabel.text=[arr valueForKey:@"id"];

    }

    else if (indexPath.row==1)

    {

        cell.textLabel.text=[arr valueForKey:@"title"];

    }

    else if (indexPath.row==2)

    {

        cell.textLabel.text=[arr valueForKey:@"subtitle"];





    }

    else if (indexPath.row==3)

    {

        cell.textLabel.text=[arr valueForKey:@"description"];





    }



    return cell;



}



//- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

//{

//    return mutarray.count;

//}



- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

{

    return request;

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

{



}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{

    [mutdata appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

    mutarray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mutdata options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    arr=[mutarray valueForKey:@"0"];



    imgarr=[mutarray valueForKey:@"images"];

    s=[[imgarr objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"image"];



    NSString *f=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://irtech.com/wecare/uploads/partnership/%@",s];



    NSURL *g=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:f];

    data=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:g];

    self.imgvw.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

    [_tbl reloadData];

}



- (IBAction)clickclick:(id)sender



{ ++index;

    s=[[imgarr objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"image"];



    NSString *f=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://irtech.com/wecare/uploads/partnership/%@",s];



    NSURL *g=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:f];

    data=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:g];

    self.imgvw.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];



}
```