# How do I extract a value from the following code?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray

How do I extract just the "token" value from the following code? I'm looking to save this value into a string.

Is meta an array? If so how would I extract the data from the "token" value?

thanks for any help

```
 NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


Response ==> {"meta":[],"data":{"token":"IVZ2ciRkbVtDLUl3YmhwOTkyXzpRR1M3LUUsRiElfWF6T3I6dCxsRWg6di1XcyR6OTUzZHhVazdLTEJ7blU5O258d2xRTXg0VUxwQXBlNHRSOXd2VXZ1aG1RfFhQQjJsSkkoc2IuOTFyYkYodyhAe2RldXR1aDF3RClXWyhoMiU="}}
2013-07-19 15:10:23.139 appName [11190:907] {
    data =     {
        token = "IVZ2ciRkbVtDLUl3YmhwOTkyXzpRR1M3LUUsRiElfWF6T3I6dCxsRWg6di1XcyR6OTUzZHhVazdLTEJ7blU5O258d2xRTXg0VUxwQXBlNHRSOXd2VXZ1aG1RfFhQQjJsSkkoc2IuOTFyYkYodyhAe2RldXR1aDF3RClXWyhoMiU=";
    };
    meta =     (
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the data is in JSON format. In that case, this should work.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&error];
NSString *token = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"token"];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Case, `meta` is an `Array` and `data` is a `Dictionary`. If your Response is properly formatted in JSON then you can use the below sample code to get the `TokenString` and `metaArray`.

**Sample Code :**

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURL];
NSError* error = nil;
NSDictionary* responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *token = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"token"];
NSArray *meta = [responseDict objectForKey:@"meta"];
NSLog(@"\ntoken :: %@\nmeta :: %@",token,meta);
```

**PS :** *To know more about JSON response , take a look at this* [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17025824/1603072).

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do this:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURL];
NSString *token = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
  options:kNilOptions error:NULL][@"data"][@"token"];
```

It will be `nil` if there's any error.